# Extend battery life with a power-controlling microcontroller?

Tags: battery

**[This article](http://alanbmitchell.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/design-of-the-extended-battery-life-power-controller-for-the-arduino/)** describes a method to extend the battery life: use a low-power controller to switch on the Arduino only when needed. The author states that this method uses considerably less power than using Arduino's sleep mode.

**Are there downsides to this approach? Which variant should I build?**(The [TPS61240 variant](http://alanbmitchell.wordpress.com/2011/11/07/arduino-power-controller-with-texas-instruments%E2%80%99-tps61240/) seems to use something from Circuits@Home that's not available anymore.) **I'd appreciate schematics or links to detailed instructions.**

Background: I'm building a sensor device that's in an environment with no mains power supply. The sensor should wake up eg. hourly, read eg. a temperature sensor, possibly send an SMS and then go back to sleep.

Comment: seems a bit overkill to use a microcontroller for that task.

Answer (score 4):

Switching off power to the board only makes sense if you're using a full Arduino. Once you strip the Arduino down to the bare MCU and decoupling capacitors (or start with a [basic breakout board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11117) instead), disabling unused peripherals and sleeping the CPU has [much more of an effect](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8349.pdf) since you no longer need to supply power to an external monitor chip.

Naturally this may involve creating your own board for the MCU. Fortunately Atmel [has the basics of that covered](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2521-AVR-Hardware-Design-Considerations_Application-Note_AVR042.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Some reasons why I thought that using an external power controller would be more simple: 1) I could use off-the-shelf Arduino board and a GSM shield. The GSM shields need momentarily a lot of current (2A), and I didn't research yet whether it would be easy to completely switch off the GSM shield from Arduino. 2) I'm not sure whether the GSM shields are compatible with `OSCCAL` and `clock_div_4` optimizations. 3) I couldn't easily find what the sleep consumption would be with a stripped down Arduino. Could you help me with these points?

Comment: A PMOSFET can handle powering down the GSM module completely if required. Clock prescaling can be set to 1 while communicating with the module, and tuning OSCCAL is completely optional. The datasheet for the MCU talks about current usage in the appropriate "Electrical Characteristics" and "Typical Characteristics" section.

Comment: There's a good chance the GSM module already has power conserving modes of its own, though perhaps those aren't readily exposed by whatever interface is used.