# Efficient periodic wake up for sensor reads

Tags: power, interrupt, timers, battery, system-design

I've been tasked to do an initial design for an Arduino setup that needs to run very infrequently.

Basically, I'd like the system to wake up *daily* to take some sensor readings and report them back to a central site (the mesh network for this will be my next stage).

Since these things are going to be run on battery, I need it to be as insanely efficient as possible, with minimal power drain when not reading the sensor.

What facilities does Arduino have to do this?

Comment: Also relevant: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/extend-battery-life-with-a-power-controlling-microcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/ArduinoSleepCode

it explains the details of a the sleep command and interrupts to re-a-wake. Where the power savings is from putting the resources individually into low power mode.

In your solution, you may want to put everything in low power, except power_timer1_disable(). Where timer1 would be configured to provide an overflow interrupt, say every 1 minute or longer and then go back to powering all off and return to sleep.

Note the article also mentions that the UNO's power supply is a linear regulator, which is very in-efficient. You may want to use your own. You can also get away with just running directly off of 2-3 AA's, if your other circuitry does not care. If this, then I would also suggest enabling the brown out detection, to ensure low battery does not get funny.